# How to move Cloud Endpoints generated sources.jar library into Android project

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

Google Plugin for Eclipse includes a facility to automatically generate the cloud endpoints client library. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to move the generated source.jar file into your Android source.

The documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android says

> The Endpoints generation results in a sources jar file. Add the
>   contents of this jar file to your Android project.

It doesn't seem possible to put the source.jar file into an Android /lib or /libs, since the source is .java rather than .class form.  So I just manually copy over the source generated by GPE (which they put in an endpoints-lib folder in your AppEngine project).  This can be extremely cumbersome especially when you have more than one endpoint and are editing it often.

See also [Error connecting android app to Google Cloud Endpoints: could not find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088110/error-connecting-android-app-to-google-cloud-endpoints-could-not-find-class)

Does anyone know of a way to actually use the sources.jar file directly in the Android project?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is solved in Eclipse by adding a linked resource to the directory at

your-appengine-project/endpoint-libs/libYourEndpoint-v1/yourendpoint/yourendpoint-generated-source/

You can do this in Eclipse by adding a source link in Properties->Java Build Path->Source Link

After this your Android or client project will see any changes generated using "Google->Generate Client Endpoint Library"

Comment: I am having the same problem. You seem to be bypassing the process. Does your app still work after you deploy it to the playstore? I mean, the idea is that your appengine code should be remote on a server somewhere and that the android code is supposed to be able to access it that way.

Comment: I think by `your-appengine-project` you really mean `your-android-project`

Comment: I do really mean your-appengine-project because that's where the library is that you are linking to.  When the .apk file is made for Android it includes all the necessary parts of the libraries, however you have linked to them in your source code.  I've been sharing folders like this with appengine connected android projects all the time.  Have you tried this yet?  It works great for me. No moving code around every time I regenerate the endpoint library.

Comment: I agree that sharing folders like that works well, but I think there is a problem with your solution.  You are generating the Android endpoint libraries into your app-engine project rather then the usual solution of generating them into an Android project.  So what happens when you generate iOS or javascript libraries?  It appears to me that Google made the mistake of using the same paths for all.

Comment: Why could you not just use the same exact technique as I described in the case of iOS or javascript?  Just do a linked resource to the proper directory.

Comment: My concern is that all generated sources will end up in <gae project folder>\endpoint-libs\libendpointname-v1\endpointname.  So, the iOS, Android, and js endpoint library files will all end up in the same place.  I don't know this for sure - I've only generated Android - and it would be surprising if they didn't account for this, but I don't see anything in the path of the generated files that distinguishes between iOS, Android, and js.  And I believe that their intention is that the generated source will always be in the client project subfolders.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that the wizard that generates the client library also copies it into your client project.

But that depends on e.g. how you initially created your projects, and even if it does work, what if you have multiple clients projects, or change your client project...  so here are some ideas:

- I found a file that specifies which project the client libraries will get copied to (in the .settings folder):
  com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.prefs:

  connectedProject=[target-android-project-name]
  eclipse.preferences.version=1

Manually changing this file worked for me, but I haven't tried manually creating it if it doesn't exist.

- The other solution, which you asked about, is to manually copy the file.  In my case I was able to copy the generated files from [gae-project]\endpoint-libs to [android-project]\endpoint-libs.  If I remember correctly, you must then find the sources jar file (it is amongst the file you copied and will be easy to find) and extract those into "[endpoint-name]-v1-generated-source" folder.  You create this folder in the same folder where you found the jar.

Clearly that is is not a great solution, so..

- There is an endpoints.cmd/bat that can be used instead of the GPE Wizard - I suggest you look to see if it has a command for copying and extracting the generated library.  I believe you would find it in the 'bin' folder of the GAE/J SDK.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I think I have finally found a simple solution, see my answer