# Call Python google cloud endpoint api from android

Tags: android, python, eclipse, google-cloud-endpoints

At this point I have created a python app-engine endpoint api called `paper` (as also noted in the `app.yaml`) file. I have placed all the jars, including the `…-java-1.13.2-beta-sources.jar` file, in the libs directory of my android project. How do I call one of my web services (aka endpoint methods)? As in I don't know the name of the package that would lead me to the api, which in the python backend is simply `class PageApi(remote.Service):`. Imagine the `paper` api has a method called `countPages(self):`. How would I call the service? I have already tried importing `import com.appspot.api.services.[etc]` but eclipse does not see the importing path.

EDIT:

I reload the api. I check that everything looks okay on api explorer. Then I found two packages that seem to be my packages -- except they contain no classes at all.

```
import com.google.api.services.page.*;
import com.google.api.services.page.model.*;
```

If they are indeed the packages, why would the classes be missing?

Comment: I am able to play with the api in api explorer. I just can't seem to get it in android (i.e. eclipse). What would the import start with?

Comment: @proppy do you have some ideas how to resolve this issue? I can see that my api exists (api explorer) and I follow the instructions for including the jars in the android project. But I can't seem to find the package where my api is actually located.

Answer (score 0):

First.  Once you have your projects setup correctly then the same wizard that generated your client library will copy it to your Android project and extra the source files.  then you will find the packages you need in the endpoint-libs folders in your project explorer.  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442841/150016) for tips on getting that working.

Then you invoke an endpoint using Android code like this:

```
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

endpointname.Builder builder = new endpointname.Builder( transport, jsonFactory, null );    
builder.setApplicationName( appName );

endpointname service = builder.build();

try {
   response = service.methodName( parameters ).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(...);
}
```

Comment: I have a python backend. No help from GEP. i.e. even after I copy your code, eclipse is still not able to suggest an import package for me.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with a python endpoint api? @bossylobster do you know how to do this?

Comment: @learner This is the code for invoking the endpoint from the Android - in answer to your question about "How do I call one of my web services (aka endpoint methods)?"  This is java because this is the Android code - so it must be Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but clearly you have not created a python backend and you have been using the Google Eclipse Plugin (maybe). Now since I am learning both ways, I have a GEP version. But then your instruction still does not work. Eclipse is still not finding `endpointname`. It has a red underline. Is this something you have successfully done? (the other post you linked to was not accepted or up voted.)

Comment: @learner  Yes, the other post I linked to was not upvoted, but the information was correct - the question is whether it helped you... You have asked about invoking endpoints from Android, so I have provided Android help and code.  Yes, I know Python and have used it on GAE, but invoking the endpoint from Android requires Java and the GPE wizard should generate (and copy) the required Java libraries into your Android project. The code above works for me but note that 'endpointname' must be replaced by the name of your endpoint.