# how to include client libraries in 2nd android application generated by GAE Backend for the 1st android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have successfully developed an android application with Google App Engine as the Backend. Now I want to develop 2nd android application and want to connect it to the same App Engine of the 1st App. In short. 2 android applications with same App Engine at the backend hence common datastore.

Could not find the detailed and satisfactory answer, please provide the answer in detail. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the first Android application connects to the App Engine backend using a REST APIo r in general a Web Service. That is the recommended route and you should be able to use the same API in your second Android Application too !

Do give more details if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: I am using eclipse, GAE Plugin, created a project then its app engine, entity class, endpoint class then client library. Used endpoint class auto-defined methods and deployed the back-end at app engine. Its working perfectly fine, now I want to create another project and that project is supposed to connect with the same deployed app engine. 1st app is saving the data and 2nd app is supposed to read the data, stored in the data store.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Since you are going to use the same backend cloud endpoints project, you need to follow the same steps that you did for the first project i.e. copy the endpoint generated android client libraries and associated JARs into your second project and use it in the same way i.e. call the relevant read methods.

Comment: I have been trying to do this but I am messed with the package imports. JARs can be places in the libs folder of my second project but what about the client libraries. Unable to resolve the package conflict

Comment: I managed to copy the endpoint libraries but I am having this exception now...... 03-28 06:32:25.393: W/System.err(1850): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
03-28 06:32:25.393: W/System.err(1850): Not Found
03-28 06:32:25.393: W/System.err(1850):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)

Comment: Most likely the endpoint URL that you are accessing is not the correct one, hence a 404.

Comment: One more thing, I am not using OAuth, I am using Public API Access to create a new key. As you know when you create the back-end it asks for the Project ID and API Key. As my second application has a different package name, is it the reason behind the 404 Exception? If yes then how to deal with it? Is it necessary to have Client IDs to access the BackEnd project with different android applications?

Comment: Well somehow it is working now... Thanks for your cooperation. Followed the steps, copied jar, copied endpoint-lib and made a source folder with endpoint-lib... It is working now. Thanks again!

Comment: Thats great! Sometimes .. just doing it fresh in a new project gets it all back to good !

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the Eclipse plug-in doesn't really support this - it will only automatically copy the generated client files into a single project.

Fortunately, there are some (manual) solutions that are discussed here:
[How to move Cloud Endpoints generated sources.jar library into Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393625/how-to-move-cloud-endpoints-generated-sources-jar-library-into-android-project/15442841#15442841)